# Where are the BTC from my paper wallet gone?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, lost-bitcoins

https://blockchain.info/de/address/12PDCamPFJexx7aVAhy6nFDxJaq7TihH6b

Hi! I got a newbie question. I sent 0,00025 BTC by Jaxx on my iPhone to a paper wallet created on bitaddress.org. The wallet pub key was 12PDCamPFJexx7aVAhy6nFDxJaq7TihH6b. I can see this transaction on blockchain.info

But now my paper wallet seems to be empty. Where are the BTCs gone? I see an outflow to 1BLgeYFimGM7Dj7PDwaN55auLv7RPevY6P, but what is this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems someone obtained your private key. If you are sure you did not authorize this transaction, consider that paper wallet compromised and never use it again. If you generated the wallet online (just by opening the website), your keys may have been stolen by malware / keylogger of some kind.

If you need to generate a paper wallet, a better way is to download [the source code](https://github.com/pointbiz/bitaddress.org) and run it on a computer disconnected form the Internet. Disable all browser extensions or use a freshly installed and up-to-date browser (e.g., if you usually use Chrome, install Firefox just for this task). Check your computer for viruses.